# Why isn't Blender using the GeForce RTX 2080 GPU and using only the Intel UHD Graphics 630?

Tags: gpu, nvidia, blender

I am setting up my computer for two things:

1. Rendering with Blender
2. Machine learning training

I have the NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 but when I start the rendering in Blender it only uses the Intel UHD Graphics card, and less than 10 percent of it (according to the Task Manager). (Also, when I use Tensorflow the GPU is not detected either.). What should I do to properly set up the NVIDIA GPU to be seen by Blender (or even Tensorflow)?

Details:

Driver: NVIDIA driver version 461.72

Platform: Windows 10 Education version 1909 Build 18363.1379

Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9700K CPU @3.6GHz 3.6GHz

GPU 0 : Intel UHD Graphics 630

GPU 1 (shown as GPU 2 in Task Manager): NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080

[Image showing the Task Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iESyP.png)

[Image showing second GPU information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7XLa.png)

Answer (score 0):

For setting the main gpu for blender, first go to settings [image] and then go to the display section in the system category [image], scroll down click on graphics settings [image]. If you have installed blender from the Microsoft store change the desktop app selection in add an app and change it to Micrsoft store app [image] and choose blender then click on options change the gpu to the RTX 2080. If you have installed using an exe or an msi file you can click on the browse button and go to the blender install path and select the app's exe file, then click on options and change the gpu

Comment: I made the change as you suggested. Blender still doesn't use the NVIDIA GPU. I then restarted the PC, to no avail. 
Btw nvidia-smi command in Powershell works. It is able to see the GPU. Thanks for your help all the same!

Comment: If you're using a pc make sure that you have the nvidia gpu in the primary  PCIe slot, instead of the secondary PCIe slot

Comment: Thanks Vishal, your solution worked after I changed the NVIDIA Graphics driver! Now Blender can see and use the NVIDIA GPU without trouble. However, Tensorflow can't see the GPU--even when I just run the Tensorflow container (docker run tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter) which the docs say only needs a graphics driver. But Pytorch can see the GPU. Thanks anyway!